# Ubuntu Server with 2 nics

Tags: networking, server, internet, dhcp

I would lik to pose a question here because i'm missing something with the settings on a ubuntu server 22.04 with 2 nics. I think it should be fairly easy because with other servers (NethServer ClearOs) it was working out of the box.

Simple set up is that the 1st nic is connecting to my isp-router and can and should get a static ip (for the moment dhcp and static are both working well to connect to internet) from this router.
The second nic should work as a DHCP-interface for my LAN. So the nic itself should have a static ip (act also as the gateway) and it should be handing out dhcp-ips to clients.
I can get dchp running and handing out ips but whatever i try, on the clients on the dchp side there is no connection to internet.

The server is headless so normally i work with cli, but i can also use cockpit (and thus also a cli within) through a webbrowser, putty or winscp to connect.

Is there anybody who can point me out the obvious because i'm sure that it can't be that complicated if you compare it to other server packages.

Thanks in advance,

What am i missing

Comment: We need to see your configs, but note that if you do DHCP on any interface and it receives a Gateway IP *that* defaults to the default gateway.

Comment: Hi, don't have the configs at this moment. Can't someone give me some basic settings for these configs (and the name of the configs)?

Comment: set up should be something like this: <public net><with dchp on isp.-router><static ip ubuntu nic 1><static ip ubuntu nic 2 which acts as dchp server for lan>. So from my isp-router i can set static ip to nic1 of ubuntu-server. On nic2 which serves the lan i should be able to set dhcp to clients and thus the nic2 itself should have a fixed ip. I can get the configs (which?) of my Nethserver with 2 nics, one external pointed and one internal pointed that works.

Comment: On my Nethserver it works out of the box just by setting up in Cockpit. Don't know why i can't achieve this in ubuntu server. My shortcomings of course:)